# Using function into template (Django/Python)

Tags: django, forms, dictionary

I'm trying to use a function that compare the keys from headers and datas of a form. If the keys aren't similar, this function adds an empty field.

It works perfectly fine in my views.py :

```
#Entries define all the datas taken from the fobi forms.

headers = json.loads(entries{0}.saved_data)
headers  = headers.items()

for key, value in headers:
    for data in entries:
        data = json.loads(data.saved_data)

        formatted[value] = data.get(key, '')
        print(entries)


formatted = formatted.items()
```

Then i pass formatted into the context and in my template i did :

```
<tr>

            {% for key, valeur in headers %}
            <th>
            {{ key }}
            </th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr> 


          </thead>
          <tbody>

                <tr>

                {% for key, valor in headers %}
                {% for cle, valeur in formatted %} 


                {%if cle == valor%}

                 <td> {{valeur}}</td>

                {% endif %}                                     
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}

                </tr>                           
          </tbody>
```

The result is perfect, such as every header is aligned with the datas. And if there are some datas missing such as picture, there is an empty sace in this column.
[image]

I only printed one form through my loop ( the last saved from the formatted dict). And i want to print all my forms. But it seems impossible in the views.py.

How i manage it into the template ?

Thank you for your answers !

BR, Karro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I created a list of dictionnaries :

```
formattedList = []
```

Then, i change my initial loop in order to get every dictionnary set in the list :

```
for entry in entries:
    formatted = {}
    for key, value in headers:

       data = json.loads(entry.saved_data)

       formatted[value] = data.get(key, '')

    formatted = formatted.items()
    **formattedList.append(formatted)**
```

Finally, i changed these lines in my template file :

```
<tbody>
                 **{%for element in formattedList%}**                
                <tr>

                {% for key, valor in headers %}
                **{% for cle, valeur in element %}**

                {%if cle == valor%}

                 <td> {{valeur}}</td>

                {% endif %}                                   
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}

                </tr>        
                 {% endfor %}            
          </tbody>
```

Everything worked fine !

I got all my results !

[image]